# Docker "/usr/bin/php" not found in container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, freeradius

I am using docker for my app that includes freeradius,nginx and php.
I want to use "program = "/usr/bin/php " this command in container freeradius but it is not working.

In freeradius container I want to run this command "/usr/bin/php" but it says command not found.

Can anyone help me in this ?

```html
version: '3.2'

services:
  freeradius:
    image: "ronakzenexim/2stacks_freeradius:v1"    
    environment:
      - RAD_DEBUG=yes
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
  php:
    image: "ronakzenexim/phpfpm72_mycrypt"
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - "./etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
        - "./web:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      - backend
 
networks:
  backend:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
```

Comment: PHP is inside its own container, not accessible by FreeRadius.

Comment: so can you please suggest me that how can I access that ?

Comment: You should write a your owne docker file which inherites from ronakzenexim/2stacks_freeradius:v1 and install PHP inside it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do with that to begin with. Maybe take a step back and rethink your goals instead of focusing on a solution that is based on a flawed approach.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt simple thing here is I want to use command line php use in my freeradius container. As freeradius need php command line access.

Comment: That's possibly the flawed approach. Consider a different approach, you provide freeradius access to the PHP container. I can't tell if either is better or worse, exactly because I don't know what you're trying achieve! Note: I know *how* you're trying to do it, but not *what* you're trying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a extension of the freeradius docker image for example

```
FROM ronakzenexim/2stacks_freeradius:v1
# Now install php
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add php7 php7-fpm php7-opcache
```

In this container you can run php.

Comment: Thanks. let me check this